# Как можно представить последовательность чисел на плоскости (x, y)?

Tags: изображения, числа, обработка-изображений

Например, вот у нас есть ряд чисел "45623459452473671673563502374152459359079460749527835122", первый способ это взять первые 8-мь цифр и присвоить определенные значения, например x = 456, y=234, а цвет = 59, и т.д.
Как их можно представить на плоскости еще ?  Каковы ваши идеи ???

Comment: Это последовательность отдельных чисел, или большое одно число из множества цифр? Просто у вас пробелов нет между числами.

Comment: Можно представлять как угодно, можно представлять также как числа после запятой, например 3,436467323424636 - и вот эти числа после "," можно взять за последовательность отдельных чисел.

Comment: Если например цель "увидеть" насколько случайные ваши цифры, то ваше представление предложенное вполне для этого подходит. Из большого числа цифр получится цветной равномерно шумный квадрат.

Comment: Ещё один способ "увидеть" степень случайности цифр - это представить наше большое число как последовательность бит, т.е. перевести в бинарный вид. Далее "рисуем" такую двумерную картину - разбиваем на пары бит, каждый первый бит это шаг по Х (+1 при бите 0 и -1 при бите 1) аналогично +-1 по У. В итоге получаются картины похожие [на эту картину](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#/media/File:Random_walk_25000_not_animated.svg). Закономерности в слабо-случайном процессе будут видны глазом на такой картине.

Comment: Почему случайных, я понимаю что получается "почти" непонятно какое изображение, но вот взять например число фи (золотое сечение) я уверен что можно получить изображение понятное для обычного человека, только нужен какой-то другой подход. Вот изображени которое я получал кое каким образом https://forum.antichat.ru/attachments/11918/ Если присмотреться можно вот здесь увидеть число 25 https://forum.antichat.ru/attachments/11919/